# ValueConverter not invoked in DataTemplate binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a `ComboBox` that uses a `DataTemplate`. The `DataTemplate` contains a binding which uses an `IValueConverter` to convert an enumerated value into a string. The problem is that the value converter is never invoked. If I put a breakpoint in `StatusToTextConverter.Convert()`, it never is hit.

This is my XAML:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusChoices, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StatusToTextConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

I thought this is how one implicitly binds to the value a `DataTemplate` is presenting. Am I wrong?

**Edit:** For context: I intend to display an `Image` in the `DataTemplate` alongside that `TextBox`. If I can't get the `TextBox` binding to work, then I don't think the `Image` will work, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some circumstances you must explicitly supply a `Path` for a `Binding`. Try this instead:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource StatusToTextConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: That works (and I had never seen that syntax before, very cool)! But it turns out I don't actually need the Path=. in there. In a fit of brilliance, I accidentally deleted the StatusChoices property in my view model. It was a fail on my part, but at least I learned something from your answer, thanks!

Comment: {Binding} and {Binding Path=.} are pretty much equivalent but I have encountered several circumstances where the other syntax must be used (with some additional binding properties of course).