# WPF, DataTemplate, Converter does not fire

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I have an issue with firing of multibinding converter when I use DataTemplate. When I remove the DataTemplate, the converter is fired.
Here is my XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstADUsers" Margin="20,5,0,20" Width="420" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  ItemsSource="{Binding ADUsers}" FontSize="11">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                     <GridViewColumn Width="420" Header="User">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2,2,2,2" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto">
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ADUserConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="UserID"/>
                                            <Binding Path="Surname"/>
                                            <Binding Path="GivenName"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Do you have an idea what might be the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2701104/2470362

Comment: @AbinMathew I saw that answer and tried it, but it still does not work.

Comment: I have tested this code and it works, there's something else going on

Comment: @VirginiaMadsen Thank you! So I need to investigate.